# Making AI chase nearest food

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, artificial-intelligence

I asked a question some time ago about how to make the AI chase the food in my Agar.io clone, which I eventually figured out myself, but now I can't figure out how to make it go after the food closest to it. I tried, by creating two arrays with the (x, y) distances between the food cells and the computer in them (as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/eubnqgyg), but the AI still goes after farther ones. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

Returning the necessary values:

```
var x = [];
var y = [];
x.push(cell.x - computerX);
y.push(cell.y - computerY);
return [Math.min.apply(null, x), Math.min.apply(null, y)];
```

Applying them:

```
this.xxx = xy()[0];
this.yyy = xy()[1];
this.dist2 = Math.sqrt(this.xxx * this.xxx + this.yyy * this.yyy);
this.speedX = (this.xxx / this.dist2) * this.speed.x;
this.speedY = (this.yyy / this.dist2) * this.speed.y;
computerX += 28 * this.speedX / computerRadius;
computerY += 28 * this.speedY / computerRadius;
```

(note: 'xy' is the function that returns the values)

How would I get the AI to try to eat the nearest food to it and not just any cell?

Comment: voting down. Relevant parts of the question to answer it are not included in the question, and "minimal test case" does not come into it. Code you have posted appears "strange":  `return [Math.min.apply(null, x), Math.min.apply(null, y)];` would seem to return `[cell.x - computerX, cell.y - computer Y]` every time since there is only one entry in the `x` and `y` arrays

Comment: Good for you? If you actually went through my jsFiddle you would have noticed the aforementioned code resides within a for loop. Also, the relevant parts _are_ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort them:

```
food.sort(function(cell1, cell2){
    var a1 = cell1.x - computerX, b1 = cell1.y - computerY,
        a2 = cell2.x - computerX, b2 = cell2.y - computerY,
        cell1Dist = Math.sqrt(a1*a1 + b1*b1),
        cell2Dist = Math.sqrt(a2*a2 + b2*b2);
    return (cell1Dist > cell2Dist)? 1 : ((cell1Dist < cell2Dist)? -1 : 0)
})
```

This assumes food = `[{x: 4, y: 3}, {x: 7, y: 9}...]`, and `computerY` and `computerX` are set, as in your question.

**edit:**

You don't need to sqrt. It's intensive, and not needed. Try this instead:

```
calcDist = function(cell){
    var a = cell.x - computer.x, b = cell.y - computer.y;
    return a*a + b*b;
}

food.sort(function(cell, cell2){
    return calcDist(cell) - calcDist(cell2);
})
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, though. The problem is I don't know how to return the shortest distance in my for loop so I can use it when I animate the AI.

Comment: @Raiden, does this work for you? I fixed the bugs, and it does sort the cells correctly. If it works, then it'd help if you can give me an up vote to show that this answer solves your problem, to show future visitors how you solved this.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was trying to implement it, but I can't quite figure out how to return the dx and dy values, seeing as how there's a1, b1, a2, and b2.

Comment: Ah - a1 is x difference from cell1, a2 is cell2,  b1 is y difference from cell1, b2 is cell2

Comment: cell1Dist is the distance from cell1, cell2Dist is the distance from cell2

Comment: So, which ones do I return?

Comment: @Raiden `(cell1Dist > cell2Dist)? 1 : ((cell1Dist < cell2Dist)? -1 : 0)`

Comment: Uh, yeah, that's already in the code. But I need the dx and dy to update the speed.

Comment: @Raiden Yes, `sort` returns a list of the closet cells - you get the first one, and you have the nearest food

Comment: Okay, but then how would I animate the AI?

Comment: @Raiden this gives you the food, sorted by distance - your code for navigating to it should work. (If not, you should create a new question about the animation)

Comment: Alright, but, um, why does the function return 1, -1, or 0 and not the actual distances?

Comment: @Raiden just the way the function works: 1: left element is bigger, 0: both are same, -1: right is bigger

Comment: Yeah, but wouldn't I require the actual values to animate it? I don't have access to them unless they're returned from the function.

Comment: @Raiden calculate it afterwords.

Comment: How? The values are only accessible in that function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96393/discussion-between-penne12-and-raiden).

Comment: Ah, there we go. I was confused because I didn't understand what Array.prototype.sort() actually did.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how to find the nearest food to the AI**

It calculates the distance between the AI (== the mouse in this demo) and 100 test food points on the canvas by applying this distance formula:

```
var dx = foods[n].x - AI.x;
var dy = foods[n].y - AI.y;
// Performance point: no need to do Math.sqrt -- you can just compare the squares
var distanceSquared = dx*dx+dy*dy;
if(distanceSquared<anyOtherDistanceSquared){
    // this is the nearest food
}
```

**Annotated example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var nearest=0;
var radius=3;

// create test foods
var foods=[];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
  var x=Math.random()*cw;
  var y=Math.random()*ch;
  foods.push({x:x,y:y});
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,PI2);
  ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
  ctx.fill();
}

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // uncolor the previous nearest
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(nearest.x,nearest.y,radius,0,PI2);
  ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
  ctx.fill();

  // get mouse x,y
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // find nearest food
  var min=10000000000000;
  for(var i=0;i<foods.length;i++){
    var f=foods[i];
    var dx=f.x-mouseX;
    var dy=f.y-mouseY;
    var testMin=dx*dx+dy*dy;
    if(testMin<min){
      min=testMin;
      nearest=f;
    }
  }

  // color new nearest
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(nearest.x,nearest.y,radius,0,PI2);
  ctx.fillStyle='red';
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move mouse and nearest "food" turns red</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: @Raiden Totally fair thanks for the upvote feedback!. Keep in mind there's *no need to do any expensive sorting* -- just scan the array of food and find the one at minimum distance. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You're not sorting points in your code as you have it right now; you're sorting x and y independently.  The line

```
return [Math.min.apply(null, x), Math.min.apply(null, y)];
```

is not the offset of the nearest food.  The nearest food may not have the smallest x displacement *or* the smallest y displacement, and while the cell may appear to be going for food that is far away, it *might be going after a point that doesn't correspond to any food at all*.  Here's an ascii-graph of what I mean.

```
X---A
| B
|
C
```

The obvious correct choice for cell `X` is food `B`, but the minimum x difference is 0 and the minimum y difference is 0.

Store points as coordinate pairs in one array, reduce by minimum distance.

Comment: @ whoever downvoted it is customary to comment with a *reason*, thank you.